# MySQL SELECT CASE WHEN column ends by number (using modulo)

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to add a column with `flag` when selecting data from MySQL table. The `flag` column should contain `0` value if column `key` (integer) ends by `0, 1 or 5`.

Table (input):

```
key      c2  c3         c4 
223432   67  20131113   20
222900   83  20131113   5415
222828   22  20131113   7354
222483   43  20131114   20
222401   28  20131113   20
```

Table (expected output - `flag` column added):

```
flag key     c2  c3         c4 
1    223432  67  20131113   20
0    222900  83  20131113   5415
1    222828  22  20131113   7354
1    222483  43  20131114   20
0    222401  28  20131113   20
```

I know the modulo function can be used to determine the last number of `key` column.

```
SELECT key % 10 as x, s.* FROM shipment s;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT case when key % 10 in (0,1,5) then 1 else 0 end as x, s.* FROM shipment s;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another two solutions.

```
SELECT IF(key % 10 in (0,1,5), 1, 0) as x, s.* FROM shipment s;
```

or simply

```
SELECT key % 10 in (0,1,5) as x, s.* FROM shipment s;
```